# Enforce space before curly brace in functions

Tags: eslint

How do I enforce having a space before a curly brace in function declarations and expressions?

E.g.

```
var badFunc = function (){
};

function badFunc(){
}


var goodFunc = function () {
};

function goodFunc() {
}
```

I found https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1618 but doesn't answer anything.

Answer (score 4):

@Unidan I believe you are looking for `space-before-blocks : 2` or however you want to set it

Answer (score -1):

This is the rule you want to use: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-before-function-paren

```
/* eslint space-before-function-paren: [2, { "anonymous": "always", "named": "always" }]*/
```

Comment: I care about space *after* the function parenthesis, not before, though.